Unable to access Jack Henry Dev Portal; receiving Authentication error
I'm trying to access the Jack Henry developer portal and authenticating via Google, but it leads to an 401 unauthorized - "Authentication error".
This is via a Google Workspace account and I see that Jack Henry specifically calls them out here but my permissions look right.
I checked my Google Workspace settings because I thought my permissions may be restricted, but I should be able to access any third party apps. Has anyone run into this before? How was it resolved?

I just tested using the developer portal login with a brand new Workspace account and did not have any issues. If you have all the correct permissions, it's possible there was a temporary issue, if you could try again.
